# Why is key.length not accurate when enumerating properties/functions

Tags: javascript

I have the following toString method in an object:

```
/**
         * @method toString
         * @public
         */
        toString: function () {
            var toString = "toString: ";
            for (key in this) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(key))   {
                    console.log(key);
                    console.log(this[key].length);
                    if(this[key].length < 50)   {
                toString +=key + ": " + this[key] + " \t ";
                    }
                }
            }
            return toString;
        }
```

Why do my functions (who have a big body of more then 50 characters) are returning length 2/3?

edit: I'm trying to get the length of the properties value to divide them in properties and functions.

edit2: since the length of a function object returns the # of params, is there an other way to divide properties and functions in js?

Comment: You are checking `this[key].length`, but if `this[key]` is a function, `this[key].length == 0`.

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Function object, [**length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property represents the total number of its formal arguments (arguments expected by the function). For example:

```
var foo = function(a) {};
foo.length; // 1
```

Note the difference between the `Function.length` and `arguments.length`:

```
var bar = function(a, b) { 
  console.log(bar.length); 
  console.log(arguments.length); 
};
bar(42);
```

This will log `2` in the first line (as the number of formal arguments is a constant value for the given function), but `1` in the second line (as `bar` is invoked with a single param only here).

---

> since the length of a function object returns the # of params, is
>   there an other way to divide properties and functions in js?

Of course: just check the property's type:

```
if (typeof this[key] === 'function') { ... }
```